# How to merge specific file from branch to another master

Tags: eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have used Git (Atlassian bit bucket) for source code management. Now the project has been hosted to live. Before live i just used to commit and push the Source code in to git. Jenkins will deploy the war. But now client has their own git and we have provided source to them. So am used to manually copy the code and paste into production git and committed using eclipse. But from end client they are not accept this approach. Without this is there any way to handle SCM as like merging our local branch to production master. This may look clumsy. But no idea how to handle.

Comment: There are several ways to copy changes from one branch to another: merging, rebasing, cherry picking. No matter which way you choose, a push is necessary at the end to upload the changes to the upstream branch of the remote repository.